# Replacing text using delimeters from a string using Regular Expression with a condition

Tags: c#, regex

I have been working with some sort of validation in which i need to make sure that the sum of digits in between two brackets is 100.
I am using **!** as my start delimeter and **|** as my ending delimeter.

> ** 90!(78!(50+50)|+22)|+10!(50 + 50)| + 20!(50 + 50 )|**

when i use  ***!.+\|***. this regular expression to replace the string
It returns me the largest substring in between them.
If i use ***!.+?\|***.
It returns me the smallest substring. 
What i need is largest in case of nested brackets and smallest in other case.
A regular expression which should return me from the above expression

90 + 10 + 20

Comment: Could you add some examples of valid and invalid input?
Wat language are you using for the expression?

Comment: I am using c sharp.
`string newString =System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(str, @"!.+\|", "", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to solve your problem using Regular Expression, then [Balancing Groups are your answer](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/balancing-groups).

But Given that the problem you're trying to solve doesn't really fit the problem domain of a Regular Expression, you'd probably be able to build a better solution using a parser/scanner.

Samples or scanner/parsers can be found easily. Some quick hits:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28294/a-Tiny-Parser-Generator-v1-2
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5676/Spart-a-parser-generator-framework-100-C
- http://irony.codeplex.com/